# how to loop through array and ftp files from the array in batch file

Tags: arrays, batch-file, ftp

Hi guys how can I loop through a variable and ftp only the files in the variable in batch programming

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Populate the array with existent files in folder
set i=0
for %%a in (*.*) do (
set /A i+=1
set list[!i!]=%%a
)
set Filesx=%i%

rem Display array elements

for /L %%i in (1,1,%Filesx%) do (
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open ftp
username
password
binary
mput !list[%%i]!
)
disconnect
```

I think I am going about it in wrong way how can i access the variable value to use mput.

Comment: There is a alternative way - make a big list of space separated files, than use `for`(No extra flags) to process them one by one.

Comment: `open`, `user`, `binary`, `mput`, `disconnect` etc. are commands to run at the FTP prompt (`FTP` without a `-s` option). Alternatively, `FTP -s:filename` takes those commands from a text file `filename`. Create such a file using wildcard(s) like`mput *` or `mput *.*`